# Вывод характеристики товара через картинку и смена title div

Tags: javascript, css

Приветствую
Есть такой див

```
<div class="field field-name-field-season field-type-list-text field-label-inline clearfix">
<div class="field-label">Сезонность:&nbsp;</div>
<div class="field-items">
<div class="field-item even">Весь год</div>
</div>
</div>
```

у

```
<div class="field-label">Сезонность:&nbsp;</div>
```

прописаны стили

```
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("images/vseses.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 100% / contain ;
```

что хотелось бы

1) добавлять после загрузки страницы к

```
<div class="field field-name-field-season field-type-list-text field-label-inline clearfix">
```

title для вывода описания

2) в зависимости от текста в

```
<div class="field-item even">Весь год</div>
```

менять картинку у дива

```
<div class="field-label">Сезонность:&nbsp;</div>
```

самый легкий вариант - через онлоад функцию прикрепленную к боди
но познаний немного не хватает

добавил скрипт, но консоль ругается

```
<script>
window.onload=function chngsz(){


        document.getElementsByClass(".field .field-name-field-season .field-type-list-text .field-label-inline .clearfix").setAttribute("title", "Item Added");
};
</script>
```

Весь див выглядит так

```
<div class="group-spec field-group-div">
    <div class="field field-name-field-season field-type-list-text field-label-inline clearfix">
        <div class="field-label">Сезонность:&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even">Весь год</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-weight field-type-number-integer field-label-inline clearfix">
        <div class="field-label">Вес:&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even">66 кг</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-length field-type-number-integer field-label-inline clearfix">
        <div class="field-label">Длина:&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even">3 100 см.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-shirina field-type-number-integer field-label-inline clearfix">
        <div class="field-label">Ширина:&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even">1 200 см.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-visota field-type-number-integer field-label-inline clearfix">
        <div class="field-label">Высота :&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even">1 200 см.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-field-crew field-type-range-integer field-label-inline clearfix">
        <div class="field-label">Экипаж:&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even">12&ndash;15 чел.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброе утро. Можно так:

js:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var elemForTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("field-name-field-season");
  var elemForImageChange = document.getElementsByClassName("field-item");
  elemForTitle[0].className += " title";
  for(el in elemForImageChange){
   if(elemForImageChange.hasOwnProperty(el)){
    switch(elemForImageChange[el].innerHTML)
     case 'Весь год': elemForImageChange[el].style.background = 'стили для фона';
     break;
     ...
     ...
   }
  }

};
```

Можно в свиче классы навешивать, а не стили проставлять. Но на мой взгляд лучше все это делать, в тот момент, когда вы создаете эти поля (.field), а то получается двойная работа.

Comment: там друпал. добавить что-то я не могу((( если б мог - я бы ID к дивам прикрутил и все. а так - мучаюсь((( 
Спасибо! щас тестану!

Comment: chngsz is not defined

<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?> onload="chngsz()">

Comment: Это вы вероятно функцию пытаетесь так обявить `window.onload=function chngsz(){` ? Используйте анонимную функцию, как в моем примере. Или правильно определяйте именную функцию: `function chngsz(){...}; window.onload = function(){chngsz();}`

Comment: @Miki Немного не то(  field-item должно проверять текст, а изменять фон у field-label. и title="title" не добавляет к диву field-name-field-season (подсказку чтобы видно было у дива)

Comment: вышло не совсем так. я поправил тайтл elemForTitleS1[0].title += " Вес изделия";
но оно меняет только у  field-item изображение, а не у field-label.